# osascript changing wallpaper with variable containing the path fails

Tags: osascript

I'm trying to run this script to change my wallpaper but I'm running into issues when the path for the file is in a variable

```
sh run.sh
wallpaper_path="$(pwd)/assets/wallpaper.jpg"
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "$(wallpaper_path)"'

33:48: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

On the other hand absolute paths work fine

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Users/stupifatcat/workspace/project/assets/wallpaper.jpg"'
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quoting the string prevents the variable from being expanded.  You will need to use additional single quotes to demarcate the string(s), or switch to double quotes and escape as needed:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "'$wallpaper_path'"'
```

or

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"$wallpaper_path\""
```

Also note that the `$()` form is a command substitution.